# Rails - Get all records for has many through relationship including unassociated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got the following classes with a has many through relationship.

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :favourites
end

class Favourite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movies
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :movies, through: :favourites
end
```

I have a search page that allows users to search for a movie by name. But I also need to show if the movie is favourited by the current user. So basically I have a query that looks something like this (reduced down to keep it relevant):

```
@movies = Movie.includes(favourites: :user)
               .where(favourites: { user: [current_user, nil] })
```

So in the above, I get all movies and I'm also attempting to get all of the current user's favourites but also return results if the movie has not been favourited yet.

The problem is though, I now have to retrieve the users favourite like:

```
@movies.each do |movie|
  movie.favourites.first # current users fav movie
end
```

Because I'm performing the query on Movie I get a collection of favourites (which makes sense) for all users but filtered down to the current user. So it's not ideal that I need to go through and check for favourites like `movie.favourites.first` - Feels a bit odd.

Is there a better query I could perform where I could perform a search on `Favourite` and get all movie results that the user hasn't favourited yet as well? Or perhaps something else.

I had through of doing something like

```
Favourite.includes(:movie)....
```

But I'm not sure how to all results including non favourited movie results for a user.

Comment: Have you considered an option to make a separate query? Something like that:
`Favourite.where(:movie_id.in => @movies.map(&:id), user: current_user)`?

Comment: @FarkhatMikhalko yeah I've considered that. I was hoping for something I could do with a single query. But atm I think what you've suggested is my only option. It would be more ideal if it was a single collection I would go through. So I don't have to check the favourited collection each time I go through each movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single query with `left join`:

```
res = Movie.left_joins(:favourites).where(fauvorites:{ user_id: [current_user.id, nil]}).
       select(Movie.arel_table[Arel.star], "(favourites.id is null) as is_favourited_by_user")
res.first.is_favourited_by_user # 0/1
```

returned `Movie` objects will have generated `is_favorited_by_user` field that indicates if particular movie is favourited by that user.

Comment: If I just did this `Movie.left_joins(:favourites).merge(current_user.favourites)` this doesn't return all movie records. If I check the count I get 11 records (instead of 6000). The current user has 11 favourited movies. So it seems to filter that down and only returns favourited movies for a user.

Comment: @kurupt_89 see updated answer - replaced `merge` with explicit `where`

Comment: that's perfect thanks. I swear I did that left_outer_joins last night exactly as you did. Must not have gotten the where condition right.

Comment: you're welcome, the catch is in `nil` - non-favorited joined records will have `NULL`s in all fields of joined `Favourite`

Answer (score 1):

I would query the list of favorite movies of the current user first and store their ids in a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

```
# in the controller
require `set`
@favorite_movies_ids = Set.new(Favourite.where(user: current_user).pluck(:movie_id))
```

With such a `Set` you can check with a very efficient `O(1)` operation if the current user favorited a specific movie and sho that information on the page – for example like this:

```
# in the view
<% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <%= 'favorite!' if @favorite_movies_ids.include?(movie.id) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

I guess that in this case, two simple queries will not be much worse than one query with a complex `JOIN` in the database.

Comment: nice, I've gone with the other answer but I like this one as well. Didn't even think of sets. I was thinking a hash lookup but set would have been nicer. Thanks :)